# fixed header not pushing content down in only some browsers

Tags: html, css

I have this page [HERE](http://www.hauppauge.com/responsive/index-fluid.htm) CSS files are [HERE](http://www.hauppauge.com/responsive/css/main-fluid.css)

The header and nav should remain fixed at the top of the page with the carousel started below it like this. [image: CORERECT]

It looks fine in most browsers but when I tested it in BrowserStack some of the browsers display it like this where the carousel image gets pushed behind the nav and header to the top: [image: Not Correct]

I cannot figure out what I am missing in the CSS. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What browsers are giving you trouble?

Comment: Figured out it was IE... surprise surprise lol

Comment: in header you have given height as 60px. Could you remove that and test again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IE is having problems with your `<main>` tag. If you explicitly set your `main#wrapper { display: block; }` it will fix this.

[Reference](http://roger.steneteg.org/blog/html5-main-element-tag-not-working-in-ie11/)

Answer (score 0):

IE and firefox won't notice the display:block nested within "main-img" you need it to be in

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your replies!

I just added to the CSS: body { padding-top: 100px; } and deleted main#wrapper { margin-top: 100px } and this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: FYI: The `margin-top` was not being recognized because browsers (IE) who don't know what the `<main>` tag is are rendering it as `display:inline;`

Comment: This is important because if you try and add any `padding` or `margin` to you main container IE will not recognize it (because it will think it's an `inline` elment) and you will have to create other workarounds. It really is best to solve the actual problem so that you get consistent styles across all browsers.

Comment: Yes I added the display:block to main#wrapper, that fixed other issues I saw happening too, thanks again!